# How can I make this body of code through a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

So, I'm trying to get this code to work in a cleaner way, mainly, through the use of a for loop, but having a really hard time trying to do so. I haven't been able to make a loop that assigns each value of the dictionary to a correspondent variable, so it can be used in the class. For context, the dictionary contains values obtained from another class, I just put those in the dict and sent it to this class, so I don't need to calculate those again.

```
    def get_ipr_data(self):
        self.reservoir_result_dict = ReservoirDataFrame.reservoir_result_dict
        self.pb = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("pb")
        self.rs = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("rs")
        self.bo = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("bo")
        self.uo = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("uo")
        self.re = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("re")
        self.j_index = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("j_index")
        self.q_max = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("q_max")
        self.pws = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("pws")
        self.qb = self.reservoir_result_dict.get("qb")
```

Comment: Why not just store the `dict` as an instance attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setattr function

```
for name in ["pb", "rs", "bo", "uo", "re", "j_index", "q_max", "pws", "qb"]:
    setattr(self, name, self.reservoir_result_dict.get(name))
```

Documentation of setattr:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I needed. Guess i need to check all those built-in functions again.

Answer (score 0):

Delegating attributes is done by defining the `__getattr__` method. You should store the dictionary only and then define `__getattr__`.

```
class Foo:
    ...

    def get_ipr_data(self):
        self.reservoir_result_dict = ReservoirDataFrame.reservoir_result_dict

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.reservoir_result_dict[item]
```